# Failed to stop regex at first Instance in Python with lazy operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
import re
f = open('temp.txt','r')
f = f.readlines()
for line in f:
   if re.match("(?=.*?termed)(?=.*?employee)", line, re.IGNORECASE):
       emp_id = line
       emp_id = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[0-9]+", emp_id,  re.IGNORECASE)[-1]
       print(emp_id)
   elif re.match("(?=.*?manager)", line, re.IGNORECASE):
        manager = line
        print(manager)
```

> technically with *? lazy operator it should stop at first finding occurrence but it keep goes on to look for further matches.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here ?

> > Sample input

```
blah blah Manager blah blah: xxa
blah blah emp_id  blah balh: 1234
xx platform : xxab
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
```

> > Expected Output

```
single line of emp_id
single line of manager name
```

Comment: Can you specify which regex has the issue, and provide an example input?

Comment: First of all, you do not need those regexps with positive lookaheads. You may just use `if all(x for x in line.lower().split() if x in ['termed', 'employee']):`. Second, what is the issue? Please provide exact text and expected output. Note with `re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[0-9]+", emp_id,  re.IGNORECASE)[-1]`, you get the last `emp_id` on a line.

Comment: @snakecharmerb `re.match("(?=.*?termed)(?=.*?employee)"` it's continuously going further without stopping on one instance and i can't break or else next loop will be none. and i have updated the example input as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's the problem i was supposed to get the last emp_id on a line but i get multiple emp_id's. and i tried the normal if else as well when i go with this approach condition will be true and it prints all of the lines where it finds the string first.

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround for this.

I initialized a blank variable in class and then if blank variable is null then run the loop or else just pass rather than breaking the loop.

```
        self.emp_id = ""
        self.manager = ""
        self.manager_need_access = ""
        self.ooo = ""
        import re
        f = open('temp.txt','r')
        f = f.readlines()
        for line in f:
            if self.emp_id == "":
                if re.match("(?=.*?termed)(?=.*?employee)(?=.*?SESA\d)", line, re.IGNORECASE):
                    self.emp_id = line
                    self.emp_id = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[0-9]+", self.emp_id,  re.IGNORECASE)[-1]
                    print(self.emp_id)
                else:
                    pass
            elif self.manager == "":
                if re.match("(?=.*?manager)(?=.*?name)", line, re.IGNORECASE):
                    self.manager = line.strip()
                    self.manager = self.manager.split(":")[1].lstrip()
                    print(self.manager)
                else:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m fairly sure it’s because you are calling it for every line. If you are wanting to stop parsing the lines there, you could put `break`.

Let me know if this works for you, and if it does, mark it as answered. Thanks :)

Comment: if i'm gonna put break then i am gonna get a null for next elif straight away, i tried it.